# R: a way to obtain the expression of a model that is fit to the data

Tags: r, visualization, mathematical-expressions

```
x = c(0:10)
y = c(0, 1, 4, 9, 15, 26, 36.6, 50, 65, 81, 104)
plot(y ~ x)
```

[image]

Suppose I have a very simple data set with 10 points. I'm trying to come up with a mathematical equation for a model that describes this data set. There are different smoothing methods in R such as `loess` and `smooth.spline`, etc that do a good job of fitting a curve to the data. My question is, is there a way in R to obtain the formula for that fit? I.e. for this toy data set it is pretty clear to see that y = x^2 would be a great choice for this data set.

For a more complicated data set, is there a way to obtain the mathematical expression for a loess curve that is fit to the data?

Comment: The entire field of statistics is dedicated to the pursuit of line fitting (and some other things). There is no easy answer here. And loess lines do not have a simple closed form, they are dependent on all the data used to make the curve. This question is not specific enough to be a programming question. You might want to consult a statistician to choose an appropriate model to fit your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a distribution which we could model with this type of power function: y = a * b^(x). Assume that nonlinear regression does not exist, we can solve this problem with "linear regression" which probably uses the least squares method. We just need to transform the axes by calculating the logarithm of both sides of the equation. Again, we just don't know "a" & "b".

ln(y) = ln[a * b^(x)] # I'm using a natural logarithm (base e).

ln(y) = ln(a) + ln(b^x)

ln(y) = [ln(b)]*(x) + ln(a) <------> Y = m(X) + B,
where m = slope, and B = vertical-intercept. I used capital B so we wouldn't get confused.

Does that look like a linear equation to you now?
So now we transform the y-axis to log<sub>e</sub>(y), get linear regression statistics, raise "m" and "B" over the base of our logarithm which is e.

so e^[ln(b)] gives us "b", and ...

e^[ln(a] gives us a,

### and then we know what y = a * b^(x) numerically.

Let's calculate that. I'm going to eliminate 0 in "x" and "y". We will lose some precision, but as you know ln(0) = -infinity. We can't have that.

x <- 1:10

y <- c(1, 4, 9, 15, 26, 36.6, 50, 65, 81, 104)

Now it would be a good idea to check that we have the same number of singular variables in "x" and in "y", or else we can't graph the points.

> length(x) == length(y)
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqXQE.jpg) TRUE

And "x" has 10 terms and so does "y" have 10 terms.

> plot(y ~ x) # Let's see what the graph looks like. You already know.

Now transform it?

> plot(log(y) ~ x))

[image: I guessed wrong]

## Hmm, this doesn't look like a straight line after the transformation.

Therefore, it's not a power function. I was wrong. Again, this log is base e.

Let's try a double logarithmic plot.

> plot(log(y) ~ log(x), main = "Double logarithmic plot to test for an exponential function", pch = 16, cex.main = 0.8)

[image: Double Logarithmic fit!]

It's a straight line, so we are in the clear. I was wrong about the power distribution. This exponential function fits the case that ...

y = a * x^(b),
which when calculating the logarithm of both sides of the equation, you get.

ln(y) = b[ln(x)] + ln(a)

so then: e^[ln(a)], where ln(a) is the vertical-intercept, = "a"

so then: b[ln(x)] or the logarithmic adjusted slope. We already have "e", no need to adjust it.

> model <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x))
>
> abline(model)
>
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = log(y) ~ log(x))

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.069478 -0.000490  0.005266  0.012249  0.031271

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.01376    0.02212  -0.622    0.551

### log(x)       2.01349    0.01330 151.360 4.06e-15 ***

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘***’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.02925 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9997,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9996 
F-statistic: 2.291e+04 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 4.06e-15

so then in our y = a * x^(b) function, to get "a", we compute ...

> exp(-0.01376)
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqXQE.jpg) 0.9863342
>
> plot(y ~ x, main = "Nonlinear Regression: y = 0.9863342 * x^(2.01349)", cex.main = 0.8)

Now, don't just trust me until you fit the curve for yourself.

> curve(0.9863342 * x^(2.01349), col = "darkorchid3", add = TRUE)

[image: Psuedo-Nonlinear Regression]

So we have finally calculate that ...

y = a * x^(b) <----------> y = 0.9863342 * x^(2.01349),
so a = 0.9863342, and b = 2.01349

Technically, I did no nonlinear regression, no iterative guesses. 
To give you a statistically correct answer I have to tell you that there are some standard errors from the least squares linear regression, and the errors adjusted in some way when I computed e^(-0.01376). But I've got a great fit.

Comment: Also, if you include zero in "x" and "y", your plot still fits perfectly.